# How to write a typehint / use a typevar for a filter method?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a helper method in Python that returns a list of methods and annotated data for each method. So it's a dict of lists. Annotated data is expressed by an `Attribute` class.

The definition is as follows:

```
# A filter predicate can be either an attribute object or a tuple/list of attribute objects.
AttributeFilter = Union['Attribute', Iterable['Attribute'], None]

# A class offering a helper method
class Mixin:
  def GetMethods(self, filter: AttributeFilter=Attribute) -> Dict[Callable, List[Attribute]]:
    pass
```

This syntax and the corresponding type check works fine.
Of cause I would like to improve it.

---

Users normally derive user-defined attributes from class `Attribute`. I would like to express, if a user passes a derived class like `UserAttribute` to `GetMethods`, that is returns a dict of lists of `UserAttribute`s.

```
# Some user-defined attribute and some public data in it
class UserAttribute(Attribute):
  someData: str

# Create a big class
class Big(mixin):

  # Annotate a method with meta information
  @UserAttribute("hello")
  def method(self):
    pass

# Create an instance
prog = Big()

# search for all methods that have 'UserAttribute' annotations
methods = prog.GetMethods(filter=UserAttribute)
for method, attributes in methods:
  for attribute in attributes:
    print(attribute.someData)
```

This code can be executed without problems, but PyCharm's type checker doesn't know that field `someData` exists for `attribute` in the last line (print call).

**Possible solution 1:**
I could use a typehint for every variable getting a return value from `GetMethods` like this:

```
methods:Dict[Callable, List[UserAttribute]] = prog.GetMethods(filter=UserAttribute)
```

This approach replicates a lot of code.

**Possible solution 2:**
Is it possible to abstract `Dict[Callable, List[UserAttribute]]` into some kind of new *generic* so I could use:

```
# pseudo code
UserGeneric[G] := Dict[Callable, List[G]]

# shorter usage
methods:UserGeneric[UserAttribute] = prog.GetMethods(filter=UserAttribute)
```

**Possible solution 3:**
At best I would like to use a `TypeVar` like this:

```
Attr = TypeVar("Attr", Attribute)

# A filter predicate can be either an attribute object or a tuple/list of attribute objects.
AttributeFilter = Union[Attr, Iterable[Attr], None]

# A class offering a helper method
class Mixin:
  def GetMethods(self, filter: AttributeFilter=Attribute) -> Dict[Callable, List[Attr]]:
    pass
```

Unfortunately, `TypeVar` expects at least 2 constraints like `T = TypeVar("T", str, byte)`.

---

At the end, this is a more complex variant of the simple example shown in the typing manual pages:

```
T = TypeVar("T")

def getElement(l: List[T]) -> T:
  pass
```

**Final question:**
How to constrain a TypeVar T to certain objects of a class and all it's subclasses, without the need of a union like in the str vs. byte example above.

*This question is related to https://github.com/Paebbels/pyAttributes.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Unfortunately, `TypeVar` expects at least 2 constraints like `T = TypeVar("T", str, byte)`.

Actually, `TypeVar` can work with just one constraint. To do so, you would do something like `T = TypeVar("T", bound=str)`.

For more details, I would recommend reading the [mypy docs on TypeVars with upper bounds](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#type-variables-with-upper-bounds) -- the official typing docs are regrettably not very polished and often cover important concepts like TypeVars with upper bounds very briefly.

---

So, that means you can solve your problem by doing this:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Union, Iterable, Dict, Callable, List

class Attribute: pass

class UserAttribute(Attribute): pass


TAttr = TypeVar("TAttr", bound=Attribute)


AttributeFilter = Union[TAttr, Iterable[TAttr], None]

class Mixin:
  def GetMethods(self,
                 filter: AttributeFilter[TAttr] = Attribute,
                 ) -> Dict[Callable, List[TAttr]]:
    pass

m = Mixin()

# Revealed type is 'builtins.dict[def (*Any, **Any) -> Any, builtins.list[test.UserAttribute*]]'
reveal_type(m.GetMethods([UserAttribute(), UserAttribute()]))
```

Some notes:

1. I named my TypeVar `TAttr`, not `Attr`. You want to make it obvious to the reader what the "placeholders" in your signatures are, so semi-common convention is to prefix your TypeVars with either `T` or `_T`. (And if you don't need an upper-bound and instead want a truly open-ended placeholder, the convention is to use a single uppercase letter like `T` or `S`.)
2. In `GetMethods(...)`, you need to do `AttributeFilter[TAttr]`. If you do just `AttributeFilter`, that's actually equivalent to doing `AttributeFilter[Any]`. This is for the same reason why doing `List` means the same thing as `List[Any]`.
3. I'm reusing `TAttr` to both define the type alias and `GetMethods` mostly for convenience, but you could also create a new TypeVar and use that for `GetMethods` if you really want: that would mean the exact same thing.
4. `reveal_type(...)` is a special pseudo-function that some type checkers (e.g. mypy and pyre) understand: it makes the type checker print out what it thinks the type of the expression is.
5. Not all type checkers (such as mypy) may support setting a default argument for a generic type. If your type checker complains, you can probably work around it by creating an overload with a no-args and single-arg variants.

Comment: I have some followup questions. For 1): I'll use this naming conversion from now on, but then `AttributeFilter` should be `TAttributeFilter`, right? For 2): `AttributeFilter` already depends on `TAttr`, why do I need to "reapply" it in `GetMethods(...)`?